# Does Javascript/jQuery have an in-built method or plugin to check the values/names of all form data?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

When using PHP and I want to find out the data being posted, I simply dump the array `$_POST` which will provide me with the `name=` attribute of all html form elements that have been submitted `input, select, textarea` etc, and their `value=` attributes in an easy to read manner.

I'm wondering if Javascript or the jQuery library has a method/plugin that does the same thing for all html form elements on the page? This would be very useful for testing out client-side validation etc.

Any answers would be greatly appreciated, as this would help me save a lot of time debugging!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has the [`serializeArray` method](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/). If you call it on a form, you'll get a list of objects containing `name`s and `value`s of fields in the form.

Comment: Brilliant! Props, I'll accept the answer then the timer drops, just what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can loop through all form elements on the page using jQuery like this:

```
$("input, textarea, select").each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("name") + " = " + $(this).val());
});
```

This will alert all the names and values on the page.